# SVProgressHud not showing in iOS 9 when app using Login with Facebook

Tags: ios, swift, ios9, facebook-sdk-4.x, svprogresshud

I am using `SVProgressHUD` in my swift project as a framework. It is working fine in iOS 8. I have login with Facebook in my app. whenever i use the login `SVProgressHUD` doesn't show through out the app. But when i killed the app and launch `SVProgressHUD` will work fine. I already added required keys in info.plist. I am unable to figure out the problem. Please anyone give the solution.

**Edit**: if i change "loginbehaviour" to Web and SystemAccount. it is working fine.

**Environment**
`FBSDK` :- 4.8.0
`XCode` :- 6.4, Swift 1.2

**LoginViewController.swift**

```
  func loginButton(loginButton: FBSDKLoginButton!,
    didCompleteWithResult
    result: FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult!,
    error: NSError!) {

        SVProgressHUD.showWithStatus(NSLocalizedString("LOGIN_PROGRESS_MSG", comment: ""))

        if (error != nil) {
            DDLogError("FB Login error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            SVProgressHUD.showErrorWithStatus(NSLocalizedString(error.localizedDescription, comment: ""))
        } else if result.isCancelled {
            DDLogError("FB Login cancelled")
            SVProgressHUD.showErrorWithStatus(NSLocalizedString("Login cancelled", comment: ""))
        } else {
            DDLogDebug("FB Login success")
            SVProgressHUD.showWithStatus(NSLocalizedString("FB_USER_FETCH_MSG", comment: ""))
            returnUserData()
        }
}
```

**Appdelegate.swift**

```
 let fbLaunch = FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(application,
            didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions) // Added this method in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method
```

also implemented

```
 func application(application: UIApplication,
    openURL url: NSURL,
    sourceApplication: String?,
    annotation: AnyObject?) -> Bool {
        return FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(
            application,
            openURL: url,
            sourceApplication: sourceApplication,
            annotation: annotation)
}

func applicationDidBecomeActive(application: UIApplication) {
    // Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.
    LocationManager.sharedInstance.startLocationManger()
    FBSDKAppEvents.activateApp()
    //Send device token change
    APNSManager.validateAndUpdateAPNSToken()

    //Look for APNS payload in background if we have saved any
    APNSManager.handlePendningAPNSPayloads()
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Svprogresshud is not showing in case of a heavy task is performing on main thread.showing loader after a delay of 4 ms will solve the problem

```
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + .milliseconds(400)) {
            SVProgressHUD.show()
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

try showing SVProgressHUD in main queue when calling from block

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
          SVProgressHUD.showWithStatus(NSLocalizedString("LOGIN_PROGRESS_MSG", comment: ""))

            })
```